# Irregular regions that respons to touch in iOS

Tags: iphone

Say I have a map for a country by regions, ex http://www.understandingitaly.com/regions.html what is the best approach to "convert" those regions into "touchable" regions that will respond and notify when I tap one of them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw your countries as bezier paths (e.g. using `UIBezierPath`), you can use the `containsPoint:` method to check whether a particular path that you've drawn contains the touch location.

Comment: Ok, that is a start, so the question comes down to how to have a UIBezierPath from an image that has irregular shape, a mono-colored center and transparent areas to the border where the irregularities are. Given that I have all the regions of map as separate images. I will try to look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer on stackoverflow.

I would try to do something like this:

with region (x, y) try to set a "touchable" area for each region.

Find out what the (x, y) center spot for each region is. Then, define a rectangular area based on the given center spot.